# Scala implicit conversion from Try to Future

Tags: scala, for-loop, future, implicit-conversion, implicit

I'm trying to mix `Try`s with `Future`s in a `for` loop in Scala, without explicitly converting the `Try`s to `Future`s with `Future.fromTry`. It looks like that it works automatically in some cases, but not in others.

The following snippet fails with

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.util._

for {
  a <- Try(5)
  b <- Future(10)
} yield { a + b }
```

> type mismatch;
>   found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Int]
>   required: scala.util.Try[?]
>    b <- Future { 10 }
>      ^
>   Compilation Failed

On the other hand if I remove the keyword `yield`, it works:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.util._

for {
  a <- Try(5)
  b <- Future(10)
} { println(a + b) }
```

It also works when I rewrite the `for` loop into a nested `foreach` or `map`:

```
@ Try(5) foreach { a => Future(10) foreach { b => println(a + b) } }
15


@ Try(5) map { a => Future(10) map { b => a + b } }
res5: Try[Future[Int]] = Success(Future(Success(15)))
```

Could someone explain me why is this happening? Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

ps. it's the same behaviour in Scala 2.11 and 2.12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foreach` returns a `Unit` type; therefore a "common" type.

Without `yield` keyword, the compiler interprets your for-comprehension as:

```
Try(5).foreach(a => Future(10).foreach(b => println(a + b)))
```

You can deal with `Future` and `Try` (two distinct monads) as long as you are chaining them around `foreach`.

If you add `yield` keyword, the compiler will interpret your for-comprehension with `flatMap`/`map`; as following:

```
Try(5).flatMap(a => Future(10).map(b => a + b))
```

The `Try#flatMap` expects a function having a `Try` as return type, but it gets a `Future`, making the whole not compiling.

**TL;DR: `foreach` does not expect matching of function types during chaining since it returns Unit in all cases; that's why it compiles.**

Note that the following:

```
Try(5) map { a => Future(10) map { b => a + b } }
```

works since `map` does not need to flatten types; so wrapping compiles with distinct "effects".
Flattening distinct types make the compiler fails; as `flatMap` attempts to do.